# Apache2 serves MS Publisher file, MS Edge/IE opens it as text

Tags: apache2, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a Microsoft Publisher file. It works just fine. I have it on Linux, in /var/www/html.

Apache2 is running with the default configuration.

I try to open it from Windows in MS Edge and IE. It displays as text (broken or no response encoding?) instead of downloading. I want to trigger Protected View for testing purposes. Why won't MS Edge or IE download the file instead of interpreting the binary file contents as HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file extension `.pub` is ambiguous, as it can refer to many MIME types (none of them being IANA assigned [media types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)):

- SSH public keys: ASCII armored text files, `text/plain`
- Microsoft Publisher documents, `application/x-mspublisher`
- Corel Ventura Publisher Publication, `application/x-pub`

By default, Apache uses `/etc/mime.types` for adding the correct [`Content-Type` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type). As there's no specified value for `.pub`, there's no `Content-Type`, and the browser is left to guess.

You could add a specific MIME type:

```
application/x-mspublisher                       pub
```

Or if you would like to force downloada, you could add the extension to:

```
application/octet-stream                        bin deploy msu msp pub
```

In addition, it's possible to add `Content-Type` for individual files with the [`ForceType` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#forcetype):

```
<Files "Microsoft.pub">
    ForceType application/x-mspublisher
</Files>

<Files "Corel.pub">
    ForceType application/x-pub
</Files>

<Files "Download.pub">
    ForceType application/octet-stream
</Files>

<Files "SSH-public-key.pub">
    ForceType text/plain
</Files>

# Default for all other .pub files
<Files ~ "\.pub$">
    ForceType text/plain
</Files>
```